# Calculator app modification

Tags: java, android

I am new in android and I created a `calculator app`. The app does the job perfectly if I give inputs like `7+8-2` , means only ADDITION and SUBTRACTION works perfectly. But if I give inputs like `4+2*3` then it calculates wrong result. I know the reason but I am not able fix this problem.

**Problem Description (My code works like this)** : Suppose I press **4**, then press **+**, then press **2**.....when I pressed **2** then immediately the calculation `4+2` happens and the result `(6)` get stored in a variable named `result`. Then suppose I press `*`, and then pressed **3**. Then again immediately the number **3** is multiplied with the value stored in variable result `(6)`, means the variable result is now `6*3 = 18` . That's why the app I created prints result of `4+2*3 = 18`, but the actual result should be `10`

> activity_simple_calculator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/infoText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/calculatorBtns"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnSeven" android:text="7" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnEight" android:text="8" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnNine" android:text="9" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnDivision" android:text="/" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnFour" android:text="4" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnFive" android:text="5" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnSix" android:text="6" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnMuliplication" android:text="X" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnOne" android:text="1" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnTwo" android:text="2" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnThree" android:text="3" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnAddition" android:text="+" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnZero" android:text="0" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnDot" android:text="." />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnEqual" android:text="=" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnSubstraction" android:text="-" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnClear" android:text="C" />

        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

> SimpleCalculator.java

```
package com.example.borntoflirt.calculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import com.example.borntoflirt.calculator.databinding.ActivitySimpleCalculatorBinding;

public class SimpleCalculator extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivitySimpleCalculatorBinding binding;

    // Declare Operators
    // This simple calculator can only perform operations of either addition, subtraction, multiplication or division.
    // So we define four static chars to represent these operations
    private static final char ADDITION = '+';
    private static final char SUBTRACTION = '-';
    private static final char MULTIPLICATION = '*';
    private static final char DIVISION = '/';

    // current action
    private char CURRENT_ACTION;

    // Declare variables for calculation
    private String digitString = "";
    private double digit;
    private double total = Double.NaN;

    private DecimalFormat decimalFormat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_simple_calculator);

        // Handle Number Clicks
        binding.btnZero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                catchDigit("0");
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "0");
            }
        });
        binding.btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                catchDigit("1");
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "1");
            }
        });
        binding.btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                catchDigit("2");
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "2");
            }
        });
        binding.btnThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                catchDigit("3");
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "3");
            }
        });
        binding.btnFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                catchDigit("4");
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "4");
            }
        });
        binding.btnFive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                catchDigit("5");
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "5");
            }
        });
        binding.btnSix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                catchDigit("6");
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "6");
            }
        });
        binding.btnSeven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                catchDigit("7");
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "7");
            }
        });
        binding.btnEight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                catchDigit("8");
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "8");
            }
        });
        binding.btnNine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                catchDigit("9");
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "9");
            }
        });
        binding.btnDot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                catchDigit(".");
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + ".");
            }
        });

        // Handle Operator Clicks
        binding.btnAddition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = ADDITION;
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "+");
            }
        });
        binding.btnSubstraction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = SUBTRACTION;
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "-");
            }
        });
        binding.btnMuliplication.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = MULTIPLICATION;
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "*");
            }
        });
        binding.btnDivision.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = DIVISION;
                binding.digit.setText(binding.digit.getText() + "/");
            }
        });
        binding.btnEqual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                computeCalculation();
                binding.infoText.setText(binding.digit.getText());
                binding.digit.setText(Double.toString(total));
                CURRENT_ACTION = '0';
                total = Double.NaN;
                digitString = "";
            }
        });
        binding.btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                binding.digit.setText(null);
                binding.infoText.setText(null);
                CURRENT_ACTION = '0';
                digitString = "";
                total = Double.NaN;
            }
        });
    }

    private void catchDigit(String dgt) {
        digitString = digitString + dgt;
    }

    private void computeCalculation() {
        if (Double.isNaN(total)) {
            total = Double.parseDouble(digitString);
            digitString = "";
        }
        else {
            digit = Double.parseDouble(digitString);

            if (CURRENT_ACTION == ADDITION) {
                total = this.total + digit;
            }
            else if (CURRENT_ACTION == SUBTRACTION) {
                total = this.total - digit;
            }
            else if (CURRENT_ACTION == MULTIPLICATION) {
                total = this.total * digit;
            }
            else if (CURRENT_ACTION == DIVISION) {
                total = this.total / digit;
            }

            digitString = "";
        }
    }
}
```

**Is the a way so that I can get the string (`ex: 4+2*3`) from `Edittext` field and then calculate the math operation..??**

Comment: Every thing is fine lets see how.

Comment: 4+2=6 and 6*2=12

Comment: think it that way instead of 4+2*2 which will result in 8

Comment: In my app 4+2*2 will print 12. Bcz 1st it calculated 4+2 = 6, then 6*2 = 12

Comment: Please review: [Order Of Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) and [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) also search on 'stack based calculator'

Comment: I know the order of operation. I just not able to set the logic because I am performing the operation in every operator click. Is there any way in Android so that I can get the string from Edittext (Ex: 4+2*3) filed and then calculate the math operation ??

Comment: Do you need to support parentheses?  In simple terms, you'll have to make your code scan the expression for * and / operators first, evaluating all of those; then scan the expression for + and - operators, evaluating those.  You can't do + and - "on the fly", because you never know when you'll get a * or / next.

Comment: You'll have do define a button which means 'execute' and/or catch the 'equals' sign so that the entire string from the EditText can then be parsed.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem and MorrisonChang you are right. I have an EQUAL sign. But how can I extract (parse) the final input 4+2*3 ?? It's in the string format. From the EditText field I can get the string but how can do the math operation in the string ???

Answer (score 0):

Given the current constraints,
especially that you don't need to support parentheses,
a simple solution could be to track the last sub-total,
and the last action,
and take them into account when performing operations of higher precedence,
such as multiplication and division.

Add fields to track the last action and sub-total:

```
private char lastAction;
private int lastSubTotal;
```

And then handle the actions like this:

```
switch (CURRENT_ACTION) {
    case ADDITION:
        total += digit;
        lastAction = CURRENT_ACTION;
        lastSubTotal = digit;
        break;
    case SUBTRACTION:
        total -= digit;
        lastAction = CURRENT_ACTION;
        lastSubTotal = digit;
        break;
    case MULTIPLICATION:
        if (lastAction == ADDITION) {
            total -= lastSubTotal;
            lastSubTotal *= digit;
            total += lastSubTotal;
        } else if (lastAction == SUBTRACTION) {
            total += lastSubTotal;
            lastSubTotal *= digit;
            total -= lastSubTotal;
        } else {
            total *= digit;
            lastAction = CURRENT_ACTION;
            lastSubTotal = digit;
        }
        break;
    case DIVISION:
        // TODO: similar to MULTIPLICATION
        break;
}
```

That is, in case of addition,
if the last action was + or -,
undo that action,
update the last sub-total,
and redo the + or -.
Also, in this case do not update the last action,
we still want to preserve the + or - in case the next action will be another multiplication or division.

Comment: Sorry to say but I don't think this is a proper way to do this.